# Type of nested object with variable keys from a list

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following two objects that define variable styles for a Button.

```js
interface colorProps {
  cyan: string;
  white: string;
  gray: string;
}

interface variantProps {
  solid: string;
  outline: string;
}

type styleProps = {  // unused
  [Key in keyof variantProps]: {[key in keyof colorProps]: string} | colorProps | string | keyof colorProps;
}

interface CustomProps {
  [key: string]: string | {[key: string]: string} | keyof colorProps | colorProps | variantProps | keyof variantProps;
}

const baseStyles: CustomProps = {
  solid: 'xxx',
  outline: 'xxx',
}

const variantStyles: CustomProps = {
  solid: {
    cyan: 'xxx',
    white: 'xxx',
    gray: 'xxx',
  },
  outline: {
    gray: 'xxx',
  },
}
```

I have defined the type of the input props for the button as such:

```
interface ButtonProps {
    href?: string;
    variant?: keyof variantProps;//'solid' | 'outline';
    color?: keyof colorProps;//'cyan' | 'white' | 'gray';
    className?: string;
}
```

I am trying to do something that I can easily do in other typed languages, namely just:

```
variantStyles[variant][color]
```

So I am trying to get the correct style based on the values of `variant` and `color`. As you can see I have tried a bunch of stuff inside `CustomProps` (apart from just typing `any`) but still I get:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'keyof colorProps' can't be used to index type 'string | colorProps | { [key: string]: string; } | variantProps'.
  Property 'cyan' does not exist on type 'string | colorProps | { [key: string]: string; } | variantProps'.ts(7053)
```

Comment: Please provide example of `variantStyles` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the CustomProps interface to:

```
interface CustomProps {
    [key: string]: {
        [key: string]: string | keyof colorProps | colorProps | variantProps | keyof variantProps;
    };
}
```